# Which interpolation algorithm does MS Paint on Windows 7 use for image rescaling?

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I was about to scale this image down to 64x64 pixels:

[image: this]

The result I got on MS Paint on Windows 7 was surprisingly good (i.e. crisp edges):

[image: ms paint rescaled] , whereas scaling it with GIMP resulted in [image: cubic GIMP] for cubic and [image: lanczos3 GIMP] for Lanczos3 interpolation, both of which look significantly worse to me. Linear and nearest-neighbor was obviously much worse still.

I have also written a small program to check all of the interpolation modes available [in the System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx), to no avail. Unfortunately, most web search results on the topic of interpolation in MS Paint are still from the days before Vista, when nearest neighbor was the only option.

Does anyone know which interpolation algorithm the Windows 7 version of MS Paint uses?

Comment: They may do some edge checking to maintain the crispness

Comment: Related: [Image downscale algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873215/image-downscale-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor plus a minimum width/height threshold below you cannot scale down.